# How to add an object to an array without copy constructor by implementing aggregation

Tags: java, arrays, aggregate

I have class Student and  I want to add Student object to the array Student in class Application by using aggregation

```
public class Student {//Start class 

private String name; 
private int id; 
private double gpa; 


public Student(String name, int id, double gpa){  
this.name=name; 
this.id=id; 
this.gpa=gpa; 
}//End class
```

Since I don't have a constructor that takes Student object as parameters  I used the getters that I already have in class Student. 
the problem my code only works with compassion
if you guys can tell me the right way to add it without making a new copy I would really appreciate it.

```
 public class Application {//Start class Application

    private Student[] studentList; 
    private int numOfStudent; 

    public Application (int size) {
    studentList= new Student[size]; }

    public void addStudent(Student s){
    if(numOfStudent<studentList.length){

    studentList[numOfStudent++]=new Student(s.getName(),s.getID(),s.getGpa()); } 
    }  
    }//End class  Application
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `javascript`?

Comment: "*my code only works with compassion*" What?

Comment: @Noura could you explain your question further so we can try to help?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, You will need to create a constructor that would accept Student object. And then you will set the variables in it like this:

```
public Student(Student s) {
this.name = s.getName();
this.id = s.getId();
this.gpa = s.getGpa();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I understood the question correctly... Do you need to create a new copy of `Student` when you add it in the array?

If not, you can simply use it as it is, i.e.

```
public void addStudent(Student s){
  if(numOfStudent<studentList.length){
    studentList[numOfstudents++] = s;
  }
}
```